# PUT Request Does not Convert Snake Case to Pascal Case

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core, webapi

I am trying to send a PUT request, but for some reason my API refuses to convert snake case properties

The request looks like this:

[image]

Where `mercuryParserResponse` looks like this in C#:

```
    [JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public class MercuryParserResponseDto
    {
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DatePublished { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Excerpt { get; set; }
        public string LeadImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("word_count")]
        public int WordCount { get; set; }
        public string NextPageUrl { get; set; } // 
        public int RenderedPages { get; set; } // 
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("total_pages")]
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    }
```

And my API endpoint

```
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(
            [FromBody]ImportArticleDto article,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

But `article.MercuryParserResponse.WordCount` is always `0` (Note that single-word properties such as `author` are coming through correctly)

Why? Why are my Json attributes not working here?

Comment: I try your codes and it's works without any problem. Do you have any other setting for your Jsonserializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299628/4671754), using `JsonPropertyName` works:

```
[JsonPropertyName("word_count")]
```

However I don't really want to have to add this to every single property

If anyone can advise how to apply this casing to the entire class I will accept your answer

Comment: Afaik, there's no exact option to cover your needs. You can only enable [case-insensitive option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#case-insensitive-property-matching)