# Setting property name to include @ in JSON using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I need to send via REST (not including some other sensitive information):

```
{"@Scope": "Local"}
```

In the class file I `JsonProperty` for Json.Net serialization:

```
[JsonProperty("@Scope")]
public string Scope { get; set; }
```

When putting together the json message to be sent via WebRequest, I have

```
{@Scope = "Local"}
```

But after running:

```
string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
```

The message being sent out is

```
{"Scope": "Local"}
```

For some reason I though System.Text.Json will pick up `JsonProperty` attributes but apparently there should be some other way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c)

Comment: is this using .net core 3.0? if so try `[JsonPropertyName("@Scope")]` ? e.g see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299628/15410

Comment: `@` is not a valid character in C# identifiers itself; it's used as an escape sequence to allow keywords to serve as identifiers. So writing `@Scope` has the same meaning as just writing `Scope`; you need to use whatever you'd normally use to override serialization to get such names as literals.

Comment: TFM - [How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties)

"To set the name of individual properties, use the [`JsonPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute) attribute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
[JsonPropertyName("@Scope")]
```

Instead of

```
[JsonProperty("@Scope")]
```

`JsonProperty` might be for Newtonsoft which the built in serialization library probably does not recognize.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This seems to work.